# How to pass a variable to lightness($color)? SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I want to create a function which will change `color` based on `background-color`lightness(), but get an error

> Argument `$color` of `lightness($color)` must be a color

When I setup `color: set-color(#000000);` everything is okay, but I need to setup varibable (`$background-color`). Is there is a way to achieve it?

```
        @function set-color($color) {
            @if (lightness($color) >= 50) {
                @return #000;
            }
            @else {
                @return #FFF;
            }
        }

        $background-color: attr(data-color);
        background-color: $background-color;
        color: set-color($background-color);
```

Comment: replace $background-color: attr(data-color) with 
$background-color: #000000

Comment: From the code it looks like u are using data-color attribute is down tag

Comment: Either add the attribute to proper element in html

Comment: Or hard code $background-color to some value

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like u are using data-color attribute is down tag.

Either add the attribute to proper element in html

Or hard code $background-color to some value

i.e. replace

```
$background-color: attr(data-color)
```

with

```
$background-color: #000000
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The colour I get dynamically from attribute. Can't make it static like $notification-confirm: hsla(101, 72%, 37%, 1); 
I need to use $background-color: attr(data-color); and then use variable as argument in the method.

Comment: @IrinaKovalchuk I see the nee